# Load json file with absolute path

Tags: javascript, json, jsp

I have a java web app running on tomcat8 on my computer.
In a jsp I have a js function loading json files from WebContent folder, but I want to load this file "/home/test/test.json".

I searched but don't find how to do it.
How can I ?

Edit: I use this

```
$('#table').bootstrapTable({
    method : 'get',
    url : '/testing/list.json',
    cache : false,
    height : 500,
    striped : false,
    pagination : false,
    search : true,
    showColumns : false,
    columns : [ {
        field : 'key',
        title : 'Key',
        align : 'left',
        valign : 'midlle',
        sortable : true
    } ]
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to serve static content from another location is to register a new context with that docbase. Check the [documentation](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/context.html) but, for short, if you create the file `$CATALINA_BASE/conf/Catalina/localhost/testing.xml` with the content

```
<Context docBase="/home/test" />
```

then you will be able to request http://localhost:8080/testing/test.json.

The name of the xml file is used as the name of the context path. Also, you don't need to have any WEB-INF or web.xml because Tomcat's defaults are usually enough.

Comment: I still have an error 404 with `GET http://localhost:8080/testing/test.json?order=asc&_=1432892924452`

Comment: Which user are you using to run tomcat? If you're running tomcat with user _tomcat_ it's home is probably at `/home/tomcat` and it may not have permissions to access `/home/test`.

Comment: I run tomcat with eclipse as test. / Edit: when I don't use eclipse and i launch as test the startup.sh it works

Comment: At the end i'll don't use eclipse and it will work but my project isn't finish yet and export the project as war and lauch tomcat each time i change something will be long

Comment: If you run tomcat from eclipse then tomcat uses a different configuration.I guess you have a `Servers` project with your tomcat there. You can edit the `server.xml` file and add the `<Context ... />` tag inside of it (inside `Host`). But in this case you need to add the attribute `path="test"` to indicate the context where it is deployed.

Comment: I tried it without the path and it didn't work, i'll try with.